# std::string_view, std::string usos y diferencias

Tags: c++

Mi pregunta es simple, ¿En qué casos me conviene usar `string_view` o `string`, y cuales son sus diferencias? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hay 1 diferencia fundamental:

- `std::string`: Administra su propia memoria.

  1. Una instancia de esta clase es responsable de la memoria usada internamente, con lo cual ésta será liberada o redimensionada según sea necesario.
  2. Son instancias autónomas. Contienen todo lo necesario para funcionar correctamente.
  3. La cadena contenida puede ser modificada.
  4. **Garantiza** que la cadena contenida tienen un caracter `0` al final de la misma.
- `std::string_view`: **No** administra su propia memoria.

  1. Es una *vista* sobre un trozo de memoria *ajeno*, que no es controlado.
  2. No tienen sentido por si mismas. Dependen del dato sobre el que actúan, salvo si están vacías.
  3. Son *vistas* de solo lectura. No se puede modificar la cadena a la que *apuntan*.
  4. **No garantiza** que exista un carácter `0` al final de la zona de memoria referenciada.

Answer (score 1):

> mi pregunta es simple

No, es más compleja de lo que parece.

> ¿En qué casos me conviene usar `string_view` o `string`, y cuales son sus diferencias?

Un primer paso para responderla, sería consultar el documento técnico de la propuesta de `std::string_view` ([N3921](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3921.html)) y averiguar cuál era la motivación tras la creación de esta herramienta (traducción mía):

> Las referencias a cadenas son muy comunes en programas C++, pero habitualmente a la función que las recibe no le importa el tipo de objeto que es propietario de los datos. 3 cosas pasan generalmente en este caso:
>
> 1. La función que recibe la cadena recibe `const std::string&` e insiste en que otras funciones copien los datos si originalmente pertenecían a otro tipo.
> 2. La función que recibe la cadena recibe dos parámetros —un `char*` y una longitud (o simplemente asume una terminación en `0`)— y reduce la legibilidad y seguridad de las llamadas además de perder las funciones que el tipo original provee.
> 3. La función que recibe la cadena se reescribe como plantilla y se mueve a una cabecera. Esto incrementa la flexibilidad si el autor programa un iterador pero también incrementa el tiempo de compilación y el tamaño del código, y puede incluso introducir bugs si el autor se olvida de asumir que los contenidos son contiguos.
>
> Google, LLVM y Bloomberg han desarrollado de manera independiente un tipo referencia-a-cadena para encapsular este tipo de argumento. `string_view` es implicitamente construible desde `const char*` y `std::string` para facilitar la conversión.

En resumen, la motivación tras la creación de `string_view` es tener una referencia constante a una cadena de texto que pudiera ser copiada con muy poco coste (1) y proveyera una colección de funciones miembro para facilitar su uso (2) sin que los tiempos de compilación ni el tamaño del código se viesen afectados (3).

Por lo tanto, conviene usar un `string_view` cuando:

- Quieras pasar cadenas o fragmentos de cadenas de texto a otras funciones.
- No necesites modificar su contenido.